# If $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k$ converges, then $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k x^k$ converges to a continuous function on $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I am almost successful in this proof but my argument needs some touches. It suffices to show that the sequence of partial sums, being continuous, converges uniformly, Then, the limit function must be continuous. Here is the question

> If $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k$ converges, then $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k x^k$ converges to a continuous function on $(-1,1)$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k$, implies that there exists $N$ such that

$$\left| \sum^{m}_{k=n+1}a_k \right|=\left| \sum^{m}_{k=0}a_k-\sum^{n}_{k=0}a_k \right|<\epsilon,\;\;\forall\;m\geq n\geq N.$$
Define 
$$A_n=\sum^{n}_{k=0}a_k $$
Since $\{A_n\}_n$ converges then it is bounded. So, there exists $M>0$ such that $$\left|A_n\right|\leq M,\;\;\forall\;n\geq 1. $$
Convergence of $\{\left|x\right|^m\}_m$ to zero implies that there exists $N_0$ such that $$\left|x\right|^m\leq \frac{\epsilon}{M},\;\;\forall\;n\geq N_0. $$
Let $m,n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m\geq n$ and $\bar{N}=\max\{N_0,N \}$. Then,

\begin{align}\left|\sum^{n}_{k=n+1}a_k x^k \right|&=\left|\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}A_k (x^k-x^{k+1}) -A_m x^m\right|\\\leq &\left|\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}A_k (x^k-x^{k+1}) -A_m x^m\right|\\\leq &\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}\left(\left|A_k\right| \left|x^k-x^{k+1}\right|\right) +\left|A_m\right| \left|x\right|^m\\<&\epsilon\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}\left|x^k-x^{k+1}\right|+M\left(\frac{\epsilon}{M}\right)\end{align}
My problem now, is how to bound $$\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}\left|x^k-x^{k+1}\right|.$$
The sequence $\{ x^k\}_k$ is decreasing only in $[0,1)$ and not in $(-1,0)$. So, I cannot have $$\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}\left|x^k-x^{k+1}\right|=\sum^{m-1}_{k=n+1}\left(x^k-x^{k+1}\right).$$
If this were possible, the proof is done. Is there any way I can bound this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean on $[-1,1]$ ? In that case see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Answer (score 3):

Let $0<\epsilon<1.$ Now, $\sup |a_k|<M<\infty$ since $\sum a_k$ converges, and ths implies that  $|a_k|\cdot | x(1-\epsilon)|^k<M$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$ so by the Weierstrass $M$-test, $\sum a_k x^k(1-\epsilon)^k$ converges uniformly--hence to a continuous function--on $(-1,1)$. But now since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: Sorry, how did you get $|a_k|\cdot | x(1-\epsilon)|^k<M$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$?

Comment: because if $x\in (-1,1)$ and $0<\epsilon<1$ then $|a_k|\cdot | x(1-\epsilon)|^k<|a_k|\cdot 1<M.$

Comment: I like very much your solution (+1) !

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I give you an alternative proof, much more simpler. From Cauchy's convergence criterion:
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n \text{ converges} \implies \limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \leq 1 $$
then
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_nx^n|} = |x|\cdot \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} <1 \implies \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_nx^n\text{ converges} $$

One way of proving that $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_nx^n$ is continuous would be by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. For any $x\in (-1, 1)$ there exist a closed interval $[a, b]\subset (-1, 1)$, such that $x$ belongs to it's interior. Then $$ |a_nx^n|\leq \max\{|a_na^n|, |a_nb^n|\} $$ and continuity follows by applying Lebesgue's theorem.

Comment: Is there any other way you can go about it? I don't want to use Lebesgue as it comes after this topic.

Comment: @Micheal The topic about Lebesgue integrals doesn't depend on this theorem and is very useful. I suggest you read it. Anyway, I wanted this more to be a cool application of this theorem.

Comment: Lebesgue's theorem on what space, $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$? How does this get you continuity? I feel like the correct application of dominated convergence requires  something like a dominating function in $\ell^1(\mathbb N ; C([a,b]))$  (which is a  messy rephrasing of Weierstrass M-test)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Heine's definition of continuity. We just take counting measure. Not sure why would you complicate it even more and introduce $l^p$ spaces. It's already simple enough. And no, I don't think it's messy, I think it's quite understandable.

Comment: I didn't say yours is messy, I said what I said is messy, because its the only way I see to apply DCT to obtain the result (It is actually just a reformulation of the standard proof, Weierstrass M-test). Sorry for the confusion. That said I do not see how the convergence of the integral $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$  for every $x$ (which is the conclusion of DCT) would imply the continuity in $x$?

Comment: (PS what I said is even worse than a usual $\ell^p$ space, it has to take values in $C([a,b])$...though I meant to say $\ell^1 (\mathbb N)$ at the start. Sorry)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Conclusion of DCT in this case is changing the order of limit and integration. In this case integration is just infinite summation.

Comment: Oh. that makes sense, thanks. Apologies for somehow missing that. I believe what confused me was that you don't use the bound you wrote down at all ( $|a_n x^n | \le \max ...$). Instead you need $|a_n y^n | \le \max ...$ for all $y$ near $x$.

Answer (score 0):

A weaker hypothesis allows to see better. I propose you a lemma in Dieudonné ``Infinitesimal Calculus'' [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence:Calcul_infinit%C3%A9simal_(Dieudonn%C3%A9))

> If $a_n$ is uniformly bounded i.e. it exists $B$ such that $|a_n|\leq B$ then 
>   $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$ converges to a continuous function in $(-1,1)$.

As pointed by Conrad, it suffices to prove uniform continuity on each $[-r,r]$ for all $0\leq r<1$. For each of these $r$ and $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, note $||f||_r=sup_{s\in [-r,r]}|f(s)|$. Then, if $a_n$ is uniformly bounded by $B$, one has
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}||a_nx^n||_r\leq B\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}r^n=\frac{B}{1-r}<+\infty
$$
which proves uniform continuity on each on each $[-r,r]$ and then continuity on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Please, how do I have access to the book?

Comment: I added the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need uniform continuity on the whole interval (-1,1) - it is enough if you show uniform continuity on (-r,r), for all r in (0,1); the hint about uniform boundedness of $|a_n|$ should allow you to deduce said uniform continuity on (-r,r) by comparison with the geometric series.

Comment: Exact ! I This hint about uniform boundedness is crucial.